# Inequality in a scalar product.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, vectors

For two nonzero vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is there an inequality similar to \begin{align*}
\langle x , y \rangle > \Vert y \Vert - \Vert x \Vert . \end{align*}By similar I mean that it would be also ok to have, for example,   \begin{align*}\langle x , y \rangle > \Vert y \Vert^2 - \Vert x \Vert^2. \end{align*}

And, if not, are there any special cases where the inequality holds? For example if I assume $\Vert y_i \Vert > \Vert x \Vert$? I have locked for similar inequalities, but somehow none seems to fit my problem.

Comment: Since $\left<x,y\right>=\left<y,x\right>$ I don't think the assumption $\|y\|\geq \|x\|$ would be useful. Also the first inequality is wrong (try $x=(0,1), y=(1000,0)$)

Comment: @Yanko Yes, you are right. Does it hold for a special case? If I assume that the vectors are not orthogonal for example?

Comment: If $x \parallel y$, say $y = \lambda x$ with $1 \lt \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\left<x , y \right> = \lVert x \rVert \lVert y \lVert = \lambda \lVert x \rVert^2$. I just cannot think of any way your inequalities would be useful to go forward from that, although you could transform the inequalities to in $\lambda$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

No. Fix $x$ and let $y$ be orthogonal to $x$ and of norm one. If the inequality would hold, then for $c\in \mathbb{R}$ we would have $$0 = \langle x,cy \rangle > \|cy\| - \|x\| = |c| - \|x\| $$

Choosing $c > \|x\|$, we obtain a contradiction. The same would hold if we were looking at an inequality of this type with the squares of the norms.

EDIT: As Yanko points out in the comments, you can also find counterexamples by making $x$ and $y$ "almost" orthogonal.

You might be interested in the polarization identity, which looks a bit similar to what you asked. It says

$$\langle x,y\rangle = \frac{\|x+y\|^2 - \|x-y\|^2}{4} = \frac{\|x+y\|^2 - \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks. What about the special cases? So for example if I assume that the two vectors are not orthogonal?

Comment: @Toribash you can always take "almost orthogonal" vectors. Another counter-example would be $x=(0,1)$ and $y=(1000,0.0001)$